# implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::future<void>' in Android

Tags: c++11, android-ndk

I am writing a Asynchronous scene loader in Android.  I have written this loader in iOS using std::future  and std::async. But same code is not working in Android.
My Scene.h is as follows:

```
    #include <future>
    class Scene
    {
       private:
       std::future<void>   mAsyncSceneLoadingHandler ;
    }
```

It shows error:

> ```
> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::future<void>'
>            std::future<void>   mAsyncSceneLoadingHandler ;
> /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/future:114:11: note: template is declared here
>        class future;
> ```

But , If I click on  std::future , its going to proper header file.

I an using Android Studio. My gradle looks like this:

```
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
   defaultConfig 
   {
       applicationId "com.ea.astosh.androidgame"
       minSdkVersion 22
       targetSdkVersion 26
       externalNativeBuild 
       {
         cmake 
         {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 -latomic"
         }
         ndk
         {
            stl = "c++_static"
         }
    }
}
```

I have checked all possible answers available, but still unable to find a solution.

I am thankful for any kind of help .

Comment: Maybe your android sdk doesn't support `std::future`?  Have you looked at the sdk header file and found any implementations?

Comment: I looked into sdk header file , it contains an implementation of std::future .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [tell **cmake**](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html#variables) to use `c++_static`:

```
cmake {
    …
    arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will  check it as soon as possible .